# Pytorch broadcasting command not found

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have the following segment of nested for loop in my code. The nested loop is slowing down my complete execution.

for a torch tensor `extended_output` with shape `[batchSize,nClass*repeat]` and another torch tensor with dimension `[batchSize,nClass]`, I want the aggregation to happen as follows:

```
for q in range(nClass):
    for u in range(repeat):
        output[:,q]=output[:,q]+extended_output[:,(q+u*nClass)]
```

Here, `nClass`,`repeat` all are integer variables with value `1400` and `8` repectively.

Can this nested for loop be avoided using pytorch broadcasting? Any help will be highly useful.

A sample working cpode might be like this

```
import torch
nClass=1400
repeat=8
batchSize=64
output=torch.zeros([batchSize,nClass])
extended_output=torch.rand([batchSize,nClass*repeat])

for q in range(nClass):
    for u in range(repeat):
        output[:,q]=output[:,q]+extended_output[:,(q+u*nClass)]
```

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the short and probably over-simplified example. I fear a bigger one would be much more difficult to visualize. But I hope this suits your purpose. Here's what I would do:

```
import torch
nClass    = 3
repeat    = 2
batchSize = 4

torch.manual_seed(0)

output          = torch.zeros([batchSize,nClass])
extended_output = torch.rand([batchSize,nClass*repeat])


for q in range(nClass):
    for u in range(repeat):
        output[:,q]=output[:,q]+extended_output[:,(q+u*nClass)]

idxs = (torch.arange(repeat)*nClass).unsqueeze(0)
idxs = idxs + torch.arange(nClass).unsqueeze(1)
output_vectorized = extended_output[:, idxs].sum(2)
```

output:

```
extended_output = 
tensor([[0.4963, 0.7682, 0.0885, 0.1320, 0.3074, 0.6341],
        [0.4901, 0.8964, 0.4556, 0.6323, 0.3489, 0.4017],
        [0.0223, 0.1689, 0.2939, 0.5185, 0.6977, 0.8000],
        [0.1610, 0.2823, 0.6816, 0.9152, 0.3971, 0.8742]])
output = 
tensor([[0.6283, 1.0756, 0.7226],
        [1.1224, 1.2453, 0.8573],
        [0.5408, 0.8665, 1.0939],
        [1.0762, 0.6794, 1.5558]])
output_vectorized = 
tensor([[0.6283, 1.0756, 0.7226],
        [1.1224, 1.2453, 0.8573],
        [0.5408, 0.8665, 1.0939],
        [1.0762, 0.6794, 1.5558]])
```

Comment: This solution does not work with other combinations of nClass    = 43
repeat    = 22
batchSize = 44

Comment: care to elaborate on how and where it fails?

Comment: you are right. there seems to be an L1 difference of 2.4780e-12 between the arrays. I'll try to look into it

Comment: It seems to be caused by numerical instability in pytorch. you get a similar error when you try to sum all the elements in 'extended_output' using a loop or using the builtin method. Go ahead and try it

Comment: This phenomenon was so interesting that I decided to ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162677/numerical-inconsistency-between-loop-and-builtin-function/68163750#68163750) about it.
You are welcomed to go take a look at some of the answers.