# Numerical inconsistency between loop and builtin function

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to compute the sum of an array of random numbers. But there seems to be an inconcistancy between the results when I do it one element at a time and when I use the built-in function. Furthermore, the error seems to increase when I decrease the data precision.

```
import torch
columns = 43*22
rows    = 44
torch.manual_seed(0)
array = torch.rand([rows,columns], dtype = torch.float64)
array_sum = 0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        array_sum += array[i, j]

torch.abs(array_sum - array.sum())
```

results in:

```
tensor(3.6380e-10, dtype=torch.float64)
```

using `dtype = torch.float32` results in:

```
tensor(0.1426)
```

using `dtype = torch.float16` results in (a whooping!):

```
tensor(18784., dtype=torch.float16)
```

I find it hard to believe no one has ever asked about it. Yet, I haven't found a similar question in SO.

Can anyone please help me find some explanation or the source of this error?

Comment: I think it is because of rounding and I tried with array_sum=torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float64). Now the difference with dtype=torch.float16 is around 12. But not around 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first mistake is this:
you should change the summation line to

```
array_sum += float(array[i, j])
```

For float64 this causes no problems, for the other values it is a problem, the explenation will follow.

To start with: when doing floating point arithmetic, you should always keep in mind that there are small mistakes due to rounding errors. The most simple way to see this is in a python shell:

```
>>> .1+.1+.1-.3
5.551115123125783e-17
```

But how do you take these errors into account?
When summing n positive integers to a total tot, the analysis is fairly simple and it the rule is:

error(tot) < tot * n * machine_epsilon

Where the factor n is usually a gross over-estimation and the machine_epsilon is dependant on the type (representation size) of floating point-number.
And is approximatly:

```
float64: 2*10^-16
float32: 1*10^-7
float16: 1*10^-3
```

And one would generally expect as an error approximately within a reasonable factor of tot*machine_epsilon.

And for my tests with float16 we get (with always +-40000 variables summing to a total of +- 20000):

```
error(float64) = 3*10^-10 ≈ 80* 20000 * 2*10^-16
error(float32) = 1*10^-1  ≈ 50* 20000 * 1*10^-7
```

which is acceptable.

Then there is another problem with the float 16. There is the machine epsilon = 1e-4 and you can see the problem with

```
>>> ar = torch.ones([1], dtype=float16)
>>> ar
tensor([2048.], dtype=torch.float16)
>>> ar[0] += .5
>>> ar
tensor([2048.], dtype=torch.float16)
```

Here the problem is that when the value 2048 is reached, the value is not precise enough to be able to add a value 1 or less. More specifically: with a float16 you can 'represent' the value 2048, and you can represent the value 2050, but nothing in between because it has too little bits for that precision. By keeping the sum in a float64 variable, you overcome this problem. Fixing this we get for float16:

```
error(float16) = 16  ≈ 8* 20000 * 1*10^-4
```

Which is large, but acceptable as a value relative to 20000 represented in float16.

If you ask yourself, which of the two methods is 'right' then the answer is none of the two, they are both approximations with the same precision, but a different error.
But as you probably guessed using the sum() method is faster, better and more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really enjoyed reading it. But the problem persists in the case of the 64bit representation. The difference between the two sums is small but never zero. I find it hard to see why there is a difference at all if the two methods perform the same operation. The machine_epsilon should be the same in both cases and cause the same errors resulting in the same sum. Unless I'm missing smth.

Comment: The problem is in the < sign. This analysis gives an upper bound, but no real value for the error. As I explained in another comment, the summation is not commutative for floating points (.1+.1+.1-.3 != .1+.1-.3+.1 on a computer). Torch doesn't specify an order for the summation.
And it can be counter-intuitive that it gives this error, but this difference is really is no problem. Both summations are equally 'right' or better equally accurate.
But I encourage you to read a little about this phenomenon, for ex. here: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs357/fa2019/references/ref-1-fp/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float(array[i][j])` in place of `array[i][j]` in order to ensure `~0` difference between the `loop-based` sum and the `torch.sum()`. The `~0` is easy to observe when the number of elements are taken into account as shown in the two plots below.

The heatmaps below show the error per element = (absolute difference between `torch.sum()` and `loop-based sum`), `divided by` the number of elements. The heatmap value when using an array of `r` rows and `c` columns is computed as:

```
     heatmap[r, c] = torch.abs(array_sum - array.sum())/ (r*c)
```

We vary the size of the array in order to observe how it affects the errors per element. Now, in the case of OP's code, the heatmaps show accumulating error with increasing size of matrix. However, when we use `float(array[i,j])`, the error is not dependent on the size of the array.

**Top Image**: when using  `array_sum += float(array[i][j])`

[image]

**Bottom Image:** when using `array_sum += (array[i][j])`
[image]

The script used to generate these plots is reproduced below if someone wants to fiddle around with these.

```
import torch
import numpy as np


column_list = range(1,200,10)
row_list = range(1,200,10)

heatmap = np.zeros(shape=(len(row_list), len(column_list)))

for count_r, rows in enumerate(row_list):
    for count_c, columns in enumerate(column_list):
        
        ### OP's snippet start
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        array = torch.rand([rows,columns], dtype = torch.float16)
        array_sum = np.float16(0)
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                array_sum += (array[i, j])
        ### OP's snippet end

        heatmap[count_r, count_c] = torch.abs(array_sum - array.sum())/ (rows*columns)
        
        
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

X = row_list
Y = column_list
Z = heatmap

df = pd.DataFrame(data=Z, columns=X, index=Y)
sns.heatmap(df, square=False)
plt.xlabel('number of rows')
plt.ylabel('number of columns')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('image_1.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This made the error smaller, but never 0.

Comment: @yannziselman While your concern "_but never 0_" is totally justified, the distribution of per-element error should clarify my point

Answer (score 0):

You have hit the top of a rather big iceberg wrt to storing high precision values in a computer.

There are two concerns here, one how python always stores a double floating point value, so you have casting between two different data types here leading to some of the odd behavior. Second is how floating point numbers in general work (you can read more [here](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/#floating-point-numbers)).

In general when you store a number in a float you are "guaranteed" some number of significant figures, say 10, then any values after 10 places will have some error in them due to the precision they were stored at (often denoted ε). This means that if you have a sum of two numbers across 10 orders of magnitude then ε will be significant in your answer, or (far more likely in this case) you will drop some of the values you care about because the total is much larger than one of the numbers you are adding. Below are some examples of this in `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

val_v_small = np.float(0.0000000000001)
val_small = np.float(1.000000001)
val_big = np.float(10000000)

print(val_big + val_small)  # here we got an extra .000000001 from the ε of val_big
>>> 10000001.000000002 

print(val_big + val_v_small)  # here we dropped the values we care about the val_v_small as they were truncated off v_big
>>> 10000000.0
```

Comment: But in my code, I'm seemingly doing the same thing twice (or am I?) and getting two different results. I'm not adding differet numbers of different orders of magnitude. I mean, yes, the sums change in orders of magnitude, but the summation is of the same numbers in both methods (supposedly).

Comment: You are doing mathematically the same, but the problem is that some mathematical properties are only approximately right with floating point values. For example floating point values are not commutative (try .1+.1+.1-.3 and .1+.1-.3+.1 in python). Mathematically equivalent, but it gives different results (both not 0)
Since both methods are doing the same mathematically, but torch nowhere specifies in which order it adds all the values. (and it shouldn't)

Comment: So even if you take away the type casting by say making `array_sum` a `torch.tensor` of `dtype=torch.float64` there is still some difference as you say. Although in both methods you are doing the same thing mathematically, the computer is doing different operations on the lower levels. I think the solution is that machine epsilon behaves is dependent on the exact what operations are being done in memory, which is different between summing each value separately or doing the vectorized tensor.sum() operation. A good example is how you get a different answer from `sum(sum(array))` too.

Comment: @DwightFromTheOffice, that's a beautiful example, thank you. I'm curious as to why, as Richard says, the 'machine epsilon' is a function of the order of the operations. I appreciate it if any of you could direct me to an article or a textbook that explains this phenomenon thoroughly.

Comment: machine epsilon is only a function of the bit representation, the difference comes from a 'random' factor (for which there is only an upper bound). It is a field on its own, and there are entire books written about it, so it is hard to give just one article for it. I recommend googling 'machine precision', 'machine epsilon', 'numerical analysis' and searching for articles that can help you. You can even browse youtube for information, for ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQs_wx8eoQ8