# Python Polynomial Calculation Efficiency

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pytorch, processing-efficiency

Those are parts of the PyTorch CNN model.

Since it takes more time than I want, I wonder if there is a better way to calculate it.

```
rand_params = np.random.default_rng()
rand_params = 1 - rand_params.standard_normal(size=(n_channels, n_poly, n_kernel))

def rand_poly(x_kernel):

  i = 0                     # i is originally channel index
  result = .0               # result will be numpy.float
  
  # runs on order and input kernel
  for j in range(n_poly):
    for k, x in enumerate(x_kernel):
      # polynomial centered (.5, .5)
      result = result + rand_params[i, j, k] * ((2 * (x - .5)) ** (j + 1)) + .5

  return result
```

It takes random parameters and 3x3 inputs.

And it calculates like

a0 * x1^1 + a1 * x1^2 + a2 * x1^3 + a3 * x1^4 + a4 * x2^1 + ...

I want the order maximum of four.

```
out = torch.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,self.filters,12,12))
for bat, image in enumerate(inputs):
    for j in range(1, 13, 1):
        for k in range(1, 13, 1):
            for i in range(self.filters):
                nl_results = rand_poly(
                [
                    image[0, j - 1, k - 1].item(),
                    image[0, j - 1, k].item(),
                    image[0, j - 1, k + 1].item(),
                    image[0, j, k - 1].item(),
                    image[0, j, k].item(),
                    image[0, j, k + 1].item(),
                    image[0, j + 1, k - 1].item(),
                    image[0, j + 1, k].item(),
                    image[0, j + 1, k + 1].item()
                ]
                )
                out[bat,i,j - 1, k - 1] = nl_results
```

---

[A link to google colab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gFw-HI14I7HVwOGquaEgaNxANa9DAQki/view?usp=sharing)

Added a link

I tested 3 models of original numpy / torch_cuda / torch_cpu

Using cuda had no benefit than cpu

The modified function itself was faster, but the the whole training time was slower.

In:

```
print('\ntiming \'numpy_model\'')
%timeit -n 1 -r 5 train_model(model=np_model, opt=np_opt, n_epochs=1)

print('\ntiming \'torch_cuda_model\'')
%timeit -n 1 -r 5 train_model(model=torch_model, opt=torch_opt, n_epochs=1)

print('\ntiming \'torch_cpu_model\'')
%timeit -n 1 -r 5 train_model(model=torch_cpu_model, opt=torch_cpu_opt, n_epochs=1)
```

Out:

```
timing 'numpy_model'
epoch: 1, acc: 0.0890625, loss: 2.3038783073425293
epoch: 1, acc: 0.09296875, loss: 2.3024404048919678
epoch: 1, acc: 0.10234375, loss: 2.3013761043548584
epoch: 1, acc: 0.1359375, loss: 2.293809652328491
epoch: 1, acc: 0.1484375, loss: 2.275158643722534
1 loop, best of 5: 32.3 s per loop

timing 'torch_cuda_model'
epoch: 1, acc: 0.12265625, loss: 2.2986485958099365
epoch: 1, acc: 0.1546875, loss: 2.2827563285827637
epoch: 1, acc: 0.1953125, loss: 2.264869451522827
epoch: 1, acc: 0.240625, loss: 2.227475643157959
epoch: 1, acc: 0.2984375, loss: 2.174687147140503
1 loop, best of 5: 48.4 s per loop

timing 'torch_cpu_model'
epoch: 1, acc: 0.09609375, loss: 2.3036952018737793
epoch: 1, acc: 0.09609375, loss: 2.303217887878418
epoch: 1, acc: 0.0890625, loss: 2.3040926456451416
epoch: 1, acc: 0.1046875, loss: 2.303426504135132
epoch: 1, acc: 0.096875, loss: 2.304520606994629
1 loop, best of 5: 33.9 s per loop
```

In:

```
%timeit np_rand_poly(x_kernel=np.arange(n_kernel), params=np_rand_params, n_poly=n_poly)
%timeit torch_rand_poly(x_kernel = torch.arange(n_kernel).cuda(), params = torch_rand_params.cuda(), exponent = exponent.cuda(), n_poly = n_poly)
%timeit torch_rand_poly(x_kernel = torch.arange(n_kernel), params = torch_rand_params, exponent = exponent, n_poly = n_poly)
```

Out:

```
10000 loops, best of 5: 153 µs per loop
The slowest run took 14.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 114 µs per loop
The slowest run took 37.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 34.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: The results of your `rand_poly` call do not depend on `i`.  You can compute that before the `i` loop and just copy it into those places.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for pointing out the indexing, but it makes no significant difference...

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @yannziselman reduced some of the codes

Comment: can you make it reproducible and provide an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would vectorize your code. Since you did not provide a reproducible example I took the liberty of creating my own.
A few notes:

- The results will not be the same because of numerical inconsistencies between "manual" sequential summation and summation performed by library functions. you can read more about it in [my question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162677/numerical-inconsistency-between-loop-and-builtin-function)
- I would generally recommend not using global variables in function definitions.
- Since you're using PyTorch, I'm assuming you are an experienced python user. in that case, even on SO (maybe especially o SO) you should include more details in your question and code. even the little things like typing helps us help you more.
- Since I assume you are an experienced Python user, I alsp assume the reason you are using loops instead of vectorization is that you intend to accelerate your code using a tool such as numba. In my experience, the benefit of using numba over vectorization is meager at best and involves a lot of debugging, and unhelpful at worst. So when you can. i would suggest you stick to vectorization.
- From your code i understand that you are not interested in computation of gradients so i did not take those into account.

  ```
  import torch
  import numpy as np



   def slow(x_kernel: torch.FloatTensor, params: torch.FloatTensor, n_poly: int = 4):
       i = 0                     # i is originally channel index
       result = .0               # result will be numpy.float
       # runs on order and input kernel
       for j in range(n_poly):
           for k, x in enumerate(x_kernel):
               # polynomial centered (.5, .5)
               result = result + params[i, j, k] * ((2 * (x - .5)) ** (j + 1)) + .5
       return result

   def aBitFaster(x_kernel: torch.FloatTensor, params: torch.FloatTensor, n_poly: int = 4):
       i = 0                     # i is originally channel index
       x = 2*(x_kernel - 0.5) 
       x = x.unsqueeze(0) ** torch.arange(1, n_poly+1).reshape(-1, 1)  # NxK matrix
       x = x * rand_params[i] + 0.5 # NxK matrix * NxK matrix
       return x.sum()

   torch.manual_seed(0)
   n_channels = 1
   n_poly = 4
   n_kernel = 9
   rand_params = 1 - torch.randn(n_channels, n_poly, n_kernel)
   x = torch.arange(n_kernel)

   print('\ntiming \'slow\'')
   %timeit slow(x, rand_params, n_poly)

   print('\ntiming \'aBitFaster\'')
   %timeit aBitFaster(x, rand_params, n_poly)

   print(
       f'\nslow(x, rand_params, n_poly)({slow(x, rand_params, n_poly)}) == '
       f'aBitFaster(x, rand_params, n_poly)({aBitFaster(x, rand_params, n_poly)}) = '
       f'\n{(slow(x, rand_params, n_poly) == aBitFaster(x, rand_params, n_poly)).all()}'
   )
  ```

Output:

```
timing 'slow'
1000 loops, best of 5: 986 µs per loop

timing 'aBitFaster'
The slowest run took 41.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 40.8 µs per loop

slow(x, rand_params, n_poly)(142266.90625) == aBitFaster(x, rand_params, n_poly)(142266.890625) = 
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! Most of what you've guessed is surprisingly correct; I intended to compute the function by cuda, and the function itself is not to be optimized. However, unfortunately, your solution didn't speedup the function; it had about 10 seconds slowdown. Maybe it is because of the intermediate results as you said, or using the torch.tensor object slows down the code. If you don't mind I would post more details of this issue.

Comment: would you kindly post the results of your timing tests for the different methods you tried?

Comment: Edited the post. Since speed drops occur during training the model, it would be better to look at the entire code.